# Should a closure return value while it is assigned to a variable or constant followed by a pair of brackets?

Tags: ios, swift

The snippets is from a tutorial as followed

```
let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Photorama")
    container.loadPersistentStores {
        (description, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error setting up Core Data \(error)")
        }
    }
}()
```

it seems the closure does not return a value as it runs, thus what the variable 'persistentContainer' get from right side of assignment?

I am try to compile similar code like

```
let v:String = {
   print("hello,world!")
}()
```

and compile failed, a String type value is expected to return within closure.

Comment: Very likely a typo. Can you post a link to the tutorial? Just want to make sure there isn't any additional context to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [actual code](https://books.google.com/books?id=yjTfDwAAQBAJ&pg=SA16-PA151&lpg=SA16-PA151&dq=%22let+container+%3D+NSPersistentContainer(name:+%22Photorama%22)%22&source=bl&ots=pYUGtZEYFS&sig=ACfU3U3F72dmFvboVAooDrxhSzOLSxOv_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjiz-HE0_byAhVpVTABHeqcAz0Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22let%20container%20%3D%20NSPersistentContainer(name%3A%20%22Photorama%22)%22&f=false) ends with `return container`. What you posted won't compile.

Comment: I suggest publisher reviews chinese version of the book...amount of mistakes exist. XCode seems not showing all of errors while building...the error arises while others have been amended.